# First Object Oriented Assignment! Does this ensure that yearsWorked is not < 0?

Tags: java, oop

This is my first Object Oriented Assignment. I am kind of lost. I am not sure if I did this instruction correctly.

> "Do not allow the yearsWorked attribute to be set to values less than zero.  If an attempt is made to set  the yearsWorked attribute to less than zero, have your set method set yearsWorked to zero."

Here is my assignment

> Part 1:  of HW #9a - Employee class (class data type for Employee)
>
> Write a class named Employee (you must name it this) that has the following attributes (fields):
>   name:  The name attribute should be a String that holds an employee's first and last name
>   idNumber:  The idNumber attribute is a String that holds an employee's ID number
>   department:  The department attribute is a String that holds the name of the employee's department that they work in
>       position:  The position attribute is a String that holds the name of the employee's job title
>       yearsWorked:  The yearsWorked attribute holds the number of years the employee has worked at the company
>
> Write Get and Set methods for each attribute:  name, idNumber, department, position, and yearsWorked.
>   Do not allow the yearsWorked attribute to be set to values less than zero.  If an attempt is made to set  the yearsWorked attribute to less than zero, have your set method set yearsWorked to zero.

Here is my code

```
public class Homework9a
{
   {
   /*MEMBER FIELDS*/
      String name= ""; 
      String idNumber= ""; 
      String department="";
      String position= "";
      double yearsWorked=0;
      double years=0;
   }
   public String getName(String name)
   {
      return name;
   }

   public String getidNumber(String idNumber)
   {
      return idNumber;
   }
   public String getdepartment(String department)
   {
      return department;
   }
   public String getposition(String position)
   {
      return position;
   }
   public void yearsWorked (double yearsWorked, double years)
   {
      if(yearsWorked > 0)
      {
         yearsWorked = years;
      }
      else
      {
         yearsWorked = 0;
      } }
}
```

Comment: You should read [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: What is your question? Why do you have a years variable at all? Based on the text yearsWorked is enough. And also, should it be a double or an integer?

Answer (score 3):

1. Clear Instruction : 'Write a class named `Employee` (you must name it this)....'

   Yet you decided to name it `Homework9a`
2. there is not a single instruction that talks about an attribute called `years` yet you decided to add it.
3. Instruction clearly says "Write Get and Set methods for each attribute: name, idNumber, department, position, and yearsWorked" yet you decided to only write one Setter (which itself is incorrect)

[This content](https://youtu.be/0NPR8GFHNmE) will help you a lot. Practice, Practice and Practice.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking about

> If an attempt is made to set the `yearsWorked` attribute to less than zero, have your set method set yearsWorked to zero.

If that's the case, then this test

```
  if(yearsWorked > 0)
  {
     yearsWorked = years;
  }
  else
  {
     yearsWorked = 0;
  }
```

is *almost* correct. However, there are a few other issues here.

First, I'd suggest sticking with the standard naming conventions for your methods.

```
public void yearsWorked (double yearsWorked, double years)
```

This should be `setYearsWorked`. Also (and this is important), you should remove the `double yearsWorked` parameter - you shouldn't need it and its presence makes it unclear whether you're trying to set the parameter or the field in the method body. (In this case, it'll set the parameter, which isn't what you want).

You also want to change this line:

```
if(yearsWorked > 0)
```

To

```
if (years > 0)
```

Also, there shouldn't be `{}` around the fields.

Finally, while Java syntax doesn't technically require it, make sure you always explicitly set access modifiers for your fields.